# how to efficiiently select first or last rows from a KDB table stored on disk

Tags: kdb

For an in-memory table, I can use sublist or take syntax to retrieve first x, last x elements.

How to do this efficiently for an on-disk table which may be very large? The constraint is that I don't want to cache all the data from table to memory to run the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.Q.ind - it takes a table and (long!) indices into the table - and returns the appropriate rows
http://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#qind-partitioned-index

Comment: thanks. I was wondering if there is some source explaining how it works. But I am happy with assumption that it works more efficiently for on disk tables for now.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you can use the i column which is the row number (per partition!) on a historical.

So the first row would be `select from trade where date=first date, i = 0`
The last row would I guess be `select from trade where date=last date, i=max i`

This assumes normal partitioned by date stuff.  If you have just a non-partitioned tables, probably `select from trade where i=0` would be fine